# Fuzzy comparison on hashed strings in Python

Tags: python, hash

Newbie here working on an application to compare company strings and find matches when the strings aren't exact.

The company strings are hashed which makes it more difficult. I want to evaluate how similar the strings are to each other, after they've been hashed. (The company names are hashed due to privacy reasons.)

Ex: 
`Apple Inc.`
`Apple Inc`

I'd like to identify these strings (once hashed) as being within a certain range of similarity to each other.

I tried ssdeep for Python, but I get a 0 match for the strings above. It seems it's too sensitive for such short strings of information.

Does anyone have any other recommendations of what can be used on hashed strings to make fuzzy comparisons?

Output from ssdeep tests:

```
>>> hash1=ssdeep.hash('Apple Inc.')
>>> hash2=ssdeep.hash('Apple Inc')
>>> ssdeep.compare(hash1,hash2)
0
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: the whole point of a hashing function is that a small difference in input will give a completely new output. If you could compare hashed values to get info about closeness to the original input it wouldn't be very secure would it?

Comment: There are lots of different kinds of hashes. That's hardly the *whole* point.

Comment: Why not simply use something like levenshtein distance?

Comment: See: https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy it may perform what you are looking for

Comment: @nathan.meadows great point :-)

Comment: @BilltheLizard sure maybe not the whole point but a fundamental aspect of their use for any security/cryptography application

Comment: @jlandercy I use that lib on plain text, but for hashes it doesn't work due to the vastly different outputs. I guess the answer here is to try to normalize the company names before hashing?

Comment: See https://python-ssdeep.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html.  ssdeep hashes will not work if the input is too short.

Comment: Thanks @JasonJenkins really helpful, any other ideas when this is the case?

Comment: Perhaps instead of hashing the strings, they could be encrypted and the key is only available to the user of the comparison code.

Comment: @JasonJenkins That's a really good idea. The comparison code is running on the server. So the idea would be that the Company would get encrypted, the key decrypts the code on the server, then uses FuzzyWuzzy to compare the plain text? I really like it. I'll check to see if this meets the privacy standards!